# Alphanumeric regex pattern with definite number of characters separated by hyphen

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a set of IDs separated by hyphen which can have minimum 6 characters containing alphanumeric values and some special characters at the end, where only numeric values are not allowed.
LIKE THE FOLLOWING:

```
YUIO-10GB-BG4   ==> Should match

U-VI1.1-100-WX-Y9  ==> Should match

1-800-553-6387  ==> Shouldn't match because all are digits

T-Series  ==> Shouldn't match as all only 2 letters are capital
```

I am trying a following pattern given below with following rules, but facing difficulties for some testing queries..

```
((?=\S{6,})[A-Z]{1,}(([A-Z0-9./+~]+){0,}-){1,}[A-Z0-9./+~]+=*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/d8MFRE/5

Comment: Could you clarify on the last test case please?

Comment: maybe [`\b((?=\S{6,})[A-Z]{1,}(([A-Z0-9./+~]+){0,}-){1,}[A-Z0-9./+~]+=*)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/d8MFRE/6)

Comment: I'd suggest [`(?:^|\s)(?=\S{6,})(?=[A-Z])([A-Z0-9./+~]+(?:-[A-Z0-9./+~]+)+=*)(?!\S)`](https://regex101.com/r/rtVb5Q/1).

Comment: The above regex doesn't satisfy the condition: do not match in case of only numeric character :(

Comment: *"T-Series  ==> Shouldn't match as all only 2 letters are capital"* So any  letters must be uppercase is a requirement?

Comment: @Usha.. I think there is no way the regex above returns matches with numbers only, the `(?=[A-Z])` requires the first uppercase letter. [`1-800-553-6387` is not matched](https://regex101.com/r/zlUd26/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following regex to get all occurrences and then filter out those that do not contain a letter with `/[A-Z]/` regex:

```
/(?:^|\s)(?=\S{6,})(?=\S*[A-Z])([A-Z0-9./+~]+(?:-[A-Z0-9./+~]+)+=*)(?!\S)/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rtVb5Q/4).

**Details**

- `(?:^|\s)` - a start of string or whitespace
- `(?=\S{6,})` - 6 or more chars then
- `(?=\S*[A-Z])` - there must be at least 1 uppercase ASCII letter after 0+ non-whitespace chars
- `([A-Z0-9./+~]+(?:-[A-Z0-9./+~]+)+=*)` - Group 1:

  - `[A-Z0-9./+~]+` - 1+ uppercase ASCII letters, digits, `.`, `/`, `+`, `~`
  - `(?:-[A-Z0-9./+~]+)+` - 1+ occurrences of:

    - `-` - a `-` char
    - `[A-Z0-9./+~]+` - 1+ uppercase ASCII letters, digits, `.`, `/`, `+`, `~`
  - `=*` - 0+ `=` symbols
- `(?!\S)` - a whitespace or end of string.
  See the JS demo:

```js
var s = "1-2-444555656-54545 800-CVB-4=\r\nThe  ABC-CD40N=  is also supported onslots GH-K on the 4000 Series ISRs using the \r\nXYZ-X-THM . This SM-X-NIM-REW34= information is not captured in the table above  \r\nTERMS WITH ONLY DIGITS SHOUD NOT MATCH --> 1-800-553-6387 \r\nNumber of chars less than 6 SHOULD NOT match ---> IP-IP \r\nGH-K\r\nVA-V etc\r\n\r\nFollowing Should match\r\nYUIO-10GB-BG4: Supports JK-X6824-UIO-XK++=  U-VI1.1-100-WX-Y9\r\nXX-123-UVW-3456\r\nVA-V-W-K9\r\nVA-V-W\r\n\r\nThe following term is not matching as there is no Alphabet in first term-----------> 800-CVB-4=        \r\nThis should match\r\n\r\nCD-YT-GH-40G-R9(=) \r\nCRT7.0-TPS8K-F\r\nJ-SMBYTRAS-SUB=\r\n===============================\r\n\r\nBelow terms should NOT match\r\nGH-K\r\nVA-V-W\r\nST-M UCS T-Series <-- Should NOT match\r\n\r\n";
var m, res=[];
var rx = /(?:^|\s)(?=\S{6,})(?=\S*[A-Z])([A-Z0-9./+~]+(?:-[A-Z0-9./+~]+)+=*)(?!\S)/g;
while(m=rx.exec(s)) {
    res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: This works for 90% queries.. but I have to find a solution in case it begins with a numeric value. eg: 800-CVB-4=      At the same time it should satisfy : not all characters are numeric..

Comment: @Usha.. Solved.

Comment: The code works but I wanted only a regex pattern, to be included in existing code..without any other code additions.. Thanks for your help :)